# How can I stream data continously through netty?

Tags: java, netty

I would like to stream RTP data through socket to users on demand. I would like to stream amount of data every 100 millisecond. Initially, I think I can do it by using Netty. However, I have the problem that, when I write data through Channel.write every 100 millisecond, the client consider the data as the separate stream every time I call write. So the client application cannot work with my stream.

I think I might not create ChannelPipeline properly. I try searching the way to do it but I cannot find the example. Does somebody know the way to do this in netty?

Answer (score 1):

Using Channel.write(..) is correct. I think you just need to be sure to also include the right rtp header on each write, so they receiver can assemble everything correctly again.

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the problem that the timestamp is not correct :)

Comment: BTW, we always look for new stuff to include in netty. So if you may be interested in contribute the codec etc I would be happy to review